# How do i move to 2nd page after scraping first in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape products details from aliexpress. I have 2 questions. First, how do I scrape category and save it in csv file in front of each product and second, how do I move to the 2nd and other pages until there are no more pages available or until page 10.

This is the code I have written to find the next pages

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r

page = r.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200000664/jackets.html?spm=2114.11010108.102.4.650c649b8lfPOb')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

content = soup.find(id="pagination-bottom")

pages = content.findAll('a')

for i in pages:
    print('https:' + i.get('href'))

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import urllib.request 

filename = "alibaba.csv" 
f=open(filename, "w")

headers="product_name, price, Rating \n" 
f.write(headers)


class alibabascrape(object):
    def __init__(self, keyword):
        self.keyword = keyword

        self.url = f"https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=&SearchText={keyword}"

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'c:\geckodriver.exe')
        self.delay = 3

    def load_alibabalist_url(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "form-searchbar")))
            print("page is ready")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Too much Time")

    def extract_post_information(self):
        all_posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("list-item")
        post_title_list = []
        for post in all_posts:
            title=post.text.split("\n")
            name=title[0]
            print(name)
            price=title[2]
            print(price)
            rating = title[6]
            print(rating)
            f.write(name + "," + price + "," + rating + "\n")
            post_title_list.append(post.text)

        return post_title_list



    def extract_category(self):
        category = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("col-sub")
        print(category)


    def extract_post_urls(self):
        url_list = []
        html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
        for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "history-item product"}):
            print(link["href"])
            url_list.append(link["href"])
        return url_list


keyword = "iphone"
scrapper = alibabascrape(keyword)
scrapper.load_alibabalist_url()
scrapper.extract_post_information()
scrapper.extract_category()
scrapper.extract_post_urls()
```

Comment: Your indentation is a bit off. Please fix them first

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with pagination:

1. If you get all ref links then you can simply use for loop to iterate
   all links.
2. If you just have prev or next page link. Then use while/ do while loop to check if the link exists and then click on it.